# Creating history of data from 2d numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 2-dimensional numpy array of shape n X m (where n is large number and m >=1 ). Each column represents one attribute. An example for n=5, m=3 is provided below:

```
[[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
[10,11,12],
[13,14,15]]
```

I want to train my model on the history of attributes with history_steps = p(1< p <= n). For p=2, the output I expect (of shape (n-p+1 X m*p)) is

```
[[1,4,2,5,3,6],
[4,7,5,8,6,9],
[7,10,8,11,9,12],
[10,13,11,14,12,15]]
```

I tried to implement this in pandas by separating columns and then concatenating outputs.

```
def buff(s, n):
    return (pd.concat([s.shift(-i) for i in range(n)], axis=1).dropna().astype(float))
```

But, for my purposes a numpy based approach will be better. Also, I would like to avoid splitting and concatenating.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: pretty much all pandas functions have an equivalent in numpy since pandas uses numpy extensively under the hood. Why don't you just read numpy docs to figure it out? (Note that in most cases, replacing `pd.function` with `np.function` works!)

Comment: Yeah. I agree. However, how about not splitting the data into columns and doing buffers

Comment: To be honest I didn't get what you are trying to do exactly, what is the logic behind your desired output...

Comment: @Julien : The columns represent different attributes. While rows represent values of these attributes at particular timestamps. What I wanted is to train a machine learning model on the sequence of the attributes. I know I can do time series approaches and possibly RNN too. But, I dont know much about them

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy based approach with focus on performance using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
def strided_axis0(a, L = 2):
    # INPUTS :
    # a : Input array
    # L : Length along rows to be cut to create per subarray

    # Store shape and strides info
    m,n = a.shape
    s0,s1 = a.strides
    nrows = m - L + 1

    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided

    # Finally use strides to get the 3D array view and then reshape
    return strided(a, shape=(nrows,n,L), strides=(s0,s1,s0)).reshape(nrows,-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [27]: a
Out[27]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])

In [28]: strided_axis0(a, L=2)
Out[28]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  2,  5,  3,  6],
       [ 4,  7,  5,  8,  6,  9],
       [ 7, 10,  8, 11,  9, 12],
       [10, 13, 11, 14, 12, 15]])
```

Comment: This is new. Never knew something like this existed in numpy.

Comment: @GKS Yup, that `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` is probably the most esoteric and the most efficient thing in NumPy. Got to use it thrice within the last 24 hours to answer questions on here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dstack` + `reshape`:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
[10,11,12],
[13,14,15]])

# use `dstack` to stack the two arrays(one with last row removed, the other with first 
# row removed), along the third axis, and then use reshape to flatten the second and third
# dimensions
np.dstack([a[:-1], a[1:]]).reshape(a.shape[0]-1, -1)

#array([[ 1,  4,  2,  5,  3,  6],
#       [ 4,  7,  5,  8,  6,  9],
#       [ 7, 10,  8, 11,  9, 12],
#       [10, 13, 11, 14, 12, 15]])
```

To generalize to arbitrary `p`, use a list comprehension to generate a list of shifted arrays and then do `stack+reshape`:

```
n, m = a.shape
p = 3
np.dstack([a[i:(n-p+i+1)] for i in range(p)]).reshape(n-p+1, -1)

#array([[ 1,  4,  7,  2,  5,  8,  3,  6,  9],
#       [ 4,  7, 10,  5,  8, 11,  6,  9, 12],
#       [ 7, 10, 13,  8, 11, 14,  9, 12, 15]])
```

Comment: how does p come into picture here? What if I want p=3

Comment: Updated a method to handle the shifts.

Comment: Looks great now. Thanks a lot!